# How to control access to files at another server in Laravel

Tags: laravel, file

I have a host for my Laravel website and another (non-laravel) for stored files. Direct access to my files are blocked completely by default and I want to control access to them by creating temporary links in my Laravel site. I know how to code, just want to know the idea of how to do it (not details).

Comment: You may store your files into public folder and you can call those from another host

Comment: Did you read my explanations?

Comment: Have a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/urls#signed-urls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Laravel docs

> Temporary URLs For files stored using the s3 or rackspace driver, you
>   may create a temporary URL to a given file using the temporaryUrl
>   method. This methods accepts a path and a DateTime instance specifying
>   when the URL should expire:

```
$url = Storage::temporaryUrl(
    'file.jpg', now()->addMinutes(5)
);
```

You could also make your own solution by directing all image request through your own server and making sure the file visibility is set to private.

Here is an example of how a controller could return image from your storage

```
public function get($path)
{
    $file = Storage::disk('s3')->get($path);
    // Do your temp link solution here
    return response($file, 200)->header('Content-Type', 'image/png');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What i am using right now is Flysystem provided in laravel.Laravel Flysystem integration use simple drivers for working with local filesystems, Amazon S3 and other some space provide also. So for this doesn't matter whether is a server is laravel server or not.

Even better, it's very simple in this to switch between server by just changing server configuration in API.

As far as I know we can create temporary Url for s3 and rackspace in this also by calling temporaryUrl method. Caching is already in this.

That's the thing.

Answer (score 0):

If your files are **uploaded on an AWS S3 server**
then,

```
use Storage;


$file_path = "4/1563454594.mp4";

if( Storage::disk('s3')->exists($file_path) ) {
    // link expiration time
     $urlExpires = Carbon::now()->addMinutes(1);

     try {
           $tempUrl = Storage::disk('s3')->temporaryUrl($file_path, $urlExpires);
     } catch ( \Exception $e ) {
           // Unable to test temporaryUrl, its giving driver dont support it issue.
           return response($e->getMessage());
     }
}
```

Your temporary URL will be generated, After given expiration time (1 minute). It will expire.